# Assistance needed with password expiry notification

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to send an email to myself every week with the list of expiring passwords. I just need names and how many days left for the password change.

I can get it working with a single email for each user but I want one email listing all of them in the body. Here is what I have so far. My problem is the logic for the for loop for each user (I think anyway). Ive left out a few variables for obvious reasons. This modified from an existing one.

```
###################################
# Function to send HTML email
###################################

function send_email () 
{
# how many days before PW expiry do we start sending reminder emails?
$max_alert = 10


# Get the maximum password lifetime
$max_pwd_life=Get-maxPwdAge

$userlist = @()
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
   {$objItem = $objResult.Properties; 
   if ( $objItem.mail.gettype.IsInstance -eq $True) 
      {      
         $user_name = $objItem.name
         $user_email = $objItem.email
         #Transform the DateTime readable format
         $user_logon = [datetime]::FromFileTime($objItem.lastlogon[0])
         $result = $objItem.pwdlastset 
         $user_pwd_last_set = [datetime]::FromFileTime($result[0])

         #calculate the difference in Day from last time a password was set
         $diff_date = [INT]([DateTime]::Now - $user_pwd_last_set).TotalDays;

   $Subtracted = $max_pwd_life - $diff_date
         if (($Subtracted) -le $max_alert) {
            $selected_user = New-Object psobject
            #$selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.name[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Name" -Value $objItem.Item("givenName")
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Email" -Value $objItem.mail[0]
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastLogon" -Value $user_logon
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "LastPwdSet" -Value $user_pwd_last_set
            $selected_user | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RemainingDays" -Value ($Subtracted)
            $userlist+=$selected_user
         }
      }
   }
   
 $SMTPServer = ""
 $SMTPPort = ""
 $Username = ""
 $Password = ""
 $today = Get-Date
 $today = $today.ToString("dddd (MMM dd, yyy)")
 $date_expire = [DateTime]::Now.AddDays($days_remaining);
 $date_expire = $date_expire.ToString("dddd (MMM dd, yyyy)")
 $SmtpClient = new-object system.net.mail.smtpClient ($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
 $SmtpClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
 $SmtpClient.Host = "" 
 $smtpClient.EnableSSL = $true
 $mailmessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage 
 $mailmessage.from = "" 
 $mailmessage.To.add("")
 $mailmessage.ReplyToList.Add("")
 $mailmessage.Subject = "Passwords about to expire"
 $mailmessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
 $strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(logonCount>=0)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=65536)))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll();




 foreach ($userItem in $userlist )
   {
    if ($userItem.RemainingDays -ge 0) {

    $mailmessage.Body = @"
    <font face=Arial>
    <p>$userItem.Name $userItem.RemainingDays</p>
    </font>
"@


      
      }
   }

 $smtpclient.Send($mailmessage) 
}


send_email
# END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

It seems you are constantly overwriting the body of the $mailMessage in your foreach loop.

I'd change that to

```
# &rarr; is HTML for the right arrow symbol (→)
$body = $userlist | Where-Object {$_.RemainingDays -ge 0} | ForEach-Object {
    "<font face=Arial><p>$($_.Name) &rarr; $($_.RemainingDays)</p></font>"
}

# check if there is a mail to send:
if ($body) {
    $mailmessage.Body = $body -join "`r`n"
    Write-Host "Sending email"
    send-email
}
else {
    Write-Host "No need to send an email"
}
```

Also, I would change the code so that the one `send_email` function is only responsable for creating the email and sending it. Create another function for collecting the user data and returning that in your `$userList` variable. Call that `Get-UserData` or something, so the function name will already explain its use.

That way, you can simplify the code which makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the foreach to something like this:

```
$mailmessage.Body = "<font face='Arial'>"

foreach ($userItem in $userlist)
{
    if ($userItem.RemainingDays -ge 0)
    {
        $mailmessage.Body += "<p>$($userItem.Name) = $($userItem.RemainingDays)</p>"
    }
}

$mailmessage.Body += "</font>"
$smtpclient.Send($mailmessage)
```

Comment: Thanks! I still get a blank email like that.

Comment: Well, this should work. If you add `Write-Host $mailmessage.Body` are the users present in the output? Also add `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` to the top of your script, to catch any errors